# PHP - select MySQL column names based on their values

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a mysql table that has a column for champion names and one for each of 5 possible positions. In the position cells there is either a "1" or "0".  What I am wondering is is there a way to use some type of select statement to return the column names that equal "1" for any given champion.  I know this doesn't exist but something like this:

```
SELECT any_rows_that = 1 WHERE name = blah;
```

so say column 2 and 4 are filled with a "1" in the same row as the name "foo". when "foo" is searched, is there any way to return "2" and "4"?

EDIT: More clear example.

I have a MySQL table that has 5 columns; name, a, b, c, and d.

name can be anything.  However, a, b, c, and d can only have a value of "0" or "1". What I am trying to do is search for any given name and I get the column names (a, b, c, or d) that equal "1" for the specific name searched.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/control-flow-functions.html

Comment: not understand your problem. just provide some example make it more clearly.

Comment: @user3517652 I put a better example

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to create your own logic using the  ["mysql_field_name"](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-field-name.php)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to do it. I had to create a select of a sub selects using a union to pull each key/pair value back as a separate row so you can pull back the rows that only match 1. Having the condition of name='foo' on each row will pull back less rows to query.

The table schema as you described.

```
CREATE TABLE `test_table` (
  `name` varchar(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `a` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `b` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `c` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `d` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Some sample data

```
INSERT INTO `test_table` (`name`, `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`)
VALUES
    ('foo', 0, 1, 0, 1);
```

and here's the query

```
select *
from (
    select 'a' as column_name, a as column_value FROM test_table where name='foo'
    union
    select 'b' as column_name, b as column_value FROM test_table where name='foo'
    union
    select 'c' as column_name, c as column_value FROM test_table where name='foo'
    union
    select 'd' as column_name, d as column_value FROM test_table where name='foo'

) query_data
where column_value=1
```